# Set audio input gain/volume for iOS 5

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, audio

Is there a way to set the gain of the audio input I get from an AudioQueue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could help you:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioSession_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html

Accessing Latency and Gain Settings
  outputVolume  property
  inputGain  property
  inputGainSettable  property
– setInputGain:error:
  inputLatency  property
  outputLatency  property

Comment: Those two methods seem to be available only on iOS 6.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the AudioSession property `InputGainScalar` on iOS5. I've just posted a full answer here, with alternatives for ios6 and ios5:

[How to control hardware mic input gain/level on iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10871231/how-to-control-hardware-mic-input-gain-level-on-iphone/16420963#16420963)

This appears to be very hardware-specific, so you won't be guaranteed to get control.